# CompileSDKtarget 30 taking the screenshot is not working

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, screenshot

```
compileSdkVersion = 30
minSdkVersion = 24
targetSdkVersion = 30
```

till 29 it was working but from 30 my code stop working for taking screenshot

```
public static Bitmap getScreenShot(LinearLayout view) {
    Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getChildAt(0).getWidth(),
            view.getChildAt(0).getHeight(),
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bm);
    Drawable bgDrawable = view.getBackground();
    if (bgDrawable != null)
        bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
    else
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    view.draw(canvas);
    return bm;
}
```

in return I m getting null value

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
public static Bitmap takescreenshot(View v) {
    v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    v.buildDrawingCache(true);
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getDrawingCache());
    v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
    return b;
}
```

Comment: code will not working in Android 11 onward

Comment: ofcourse will work in android 11 and android 12 as well...